# Core Data Model Design - Attributes vs Entities

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design

I've been developing a very basic core data application for over a year now (Toy Collector, http://bit.ly/tocapp), and I'm looking at doing a redesign so that I can build in iCloud support. I figured while I'm doing that, I might as well update my core data model (if needed), and I'm having a heck of a time tracking down "best practices" for the following:

Currently, I have 2 entities:

Toy, Keywords

Toy has all the information about the object: Name, Year, Set, imageName, Owned, Wanted, Manufacturer, etc, (18 attributes in all)

Keywords has the normalized words to help speed up the search

My question is whether or not there is any advantage to breaking out some of the Toy attributes into their own entities. For example, I could have a manufacturer entity that stores the dozen or so manufacturers, instead of keeping that information in the Toy object. My gut tells me this could reduce the memory footprint (instead of 50,000 objects storing a manufacturer string, there would simple be 12 manufacturer strings in an entity with a relationship to the main Toy entity). Does that kind of organization really matter? Am I trying to overcomplicate things? I just feel like my entity has a lot of attributes, and I'm not sure if taking the time to break it apart into multiple entities would make a difference.

Any advice or pointers would be appreciated!

Zack

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty broad, since it addresses the topic of [database design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design). Let me say upfront that it is almost impossible to give you any sensible suggestions, since I would need to know a lot more about your app, use cases, etc. than it is possible through a S.O. question.

Coming to your concrete questions, I would say that you correctly identify one of advantages of splitting a table into multiple ones; actually, the advantage of doing that is not just reducing the database footprint, rather keep [data redundancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_redundancy) to a minimum. Redundancy not only affects memory footprint but also manageability and modifiability of your data, and lack of redundancy could even cause anomalies or corruption. There is even a whole database theory topic which is known as [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) that addresses this king of concerns.

On the other hand, as it is always the case, redundancy can help performance, and this is actually the case when you can fetch your data through a simple query instead of multiple queries or table joins. There is a technique to improving a database performance which is known as [database denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and is the exact opposite to normalisation. Your current scheme is fully denormalized.

Using Core Data, which is a relational object graph manager running often on top of SQLite, which is a relational database manager, you have also to take into account the fact that Core Data will automatically build your object graph and fetch into memory the data when you need it. This means that if you can take a smaller memory footprint on disk for granted, this might not be the case when it comes to RAM footprint of your query results (Core Data will "explode", so to say, at some moment your data from multiple tables into one object plus its attributes).

In your specific case, you should also possibly take into account the cost of migrating your existing user base (if the database is not read-only).

All in all, I would say that if your app does not have any database footprint issues at the moment; if you do not feel that creating new tables might be useful, e.g., in order to add new functionality, such as listing all manufacturers; and, finally, if you do not foresee tasks like renaming a manufacturer or such at some point, then maybe refactoring your database will not add much benefit. But, as I say, without knowing your app in detail and your roadmap for it, it is difficult to say anything really on spot. In any case, I hope this general considerations will help you take a decision.

EDIT:

If you want to investigate your core data performance and try to understand where the bottlenecks are, give a try to Instruments/Core Data tool (Product/Profile menu). There are a lot of things that can go bad.

On the other hand, it is really hard to help you further without having more details about the type of searches your app allows to do. One thing that is not clear to me is if your searches are slow only when they return a lot of results or they are slow even when returning a few results.

Normalizing might help performance if you only use (say, after doing a search) just one normalized entity (e.g., to display the toy name in a table). In this case all of the attributes referring to other entities would be faults (hence would not occupy memory nor take) and this might speed up things. But, if you do a search and then display the information from the other tables as well, then there might not be any advantage, quite the opposite, since the faults would have to be resolved immediately and this would produce more accesses to the database.

Also it is true that depending on how you use it, core data could not be the best way to handle your data. Have a look at this [Brent Simmons' post relating his experience.](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/SQLite-instead-of-core-data.html)

Comment: Sergio, I really appreciate the thorough response. It has given me a lot to think about (and research!) - My primary concern with my current database continues to be extremely slow search times (essentially making the search feature unusable). Perhaps that is just something I will have to accept with 50,000 objects and 20 attributes each.That is the one area that continues to disappoint my users. I have no qualms with releasing a brand new app, with a totally remodeled database, requiring users to migrate their data (it's a free app, after all), but I don't want to do that w/o a reason